# Any way to know a keyboard dimensions without showing it?

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

I would like to know whether it's possible to get a keyboard height without displaying it first. Just a system dimensions for height.

Need to display a UIView which has a keyboard equal size for current device used.

Any approaches and tricks are welcome

Comment: **I almost sure that it's impossible but may be there are any hacks exist for that particular case

Comment: How can you know ahead of time? The user could have various custom keyboards installed. The user could switch to different keyboards which might have different sizes. You can only know when a keyboard is about to be presented.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I understand that. Would be cool to have a kind of "system keyboard's" base dimensions (w/o lexicon suggestions, other fields, but just a height of area with keys). But, seems like no magic there..

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, You can also make a view appear instead of a keyboard.  [Check out inputView on UIResponder.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIResponder/inputView)

(I wanted to make this a comment but I can't -almost there! :-) )